# Covert a string of values into list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of values like this:
`2684894 1910311 4000006 1910385 760853 2982563`

but I want that to be a list of integers instead like this:
`[2684894, 1910311, 4000006, 1910385, 760853, 2982563]`

I've tried this:

```
tags = data[['id','tag']] #from another df

tags = tags.set_index('id') 

tags = tags.drop_duplicates()
tags.dropna(inplace=True)

tags['tag'] = tags['tag'].to_list()
```

But then when I print out `tags.head`, the format is the same as the original. It hasn't changed to a list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

> Split strings around given separator/delimiter.
> *pat*: str or compiled regex, optional
> String or regular expression to split on. If not specified, split on **whitespace**.

Try this :

```
tags["tag"] = tags["tag"].str.split()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(tags, type(tags.iloc[0,0]))
                                                     tag
0  [2684894, 1910311, 4000006, 1910385, 760853, 2982563] <class 'list'>
```

Comment: It does split it into a list but then when I go to iterate through that list, it throws an error because it is being parsed as an object rather than a list: `129466    ['713087', '3188919', '715859', '4000006', '31...
Name: tag, dtype: object`. The error is `ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (1)`

Comment: That's normal because there is no dtype `list` for Series. You can't do that like this. If you want to access to the first item of each list/row, you can use `tags["tag"].str[0]`, the second item `tags["tag"].str[1]` and so on...